# Is UML useful to describe templated code?

Tags: c++, oop, templates, uml

I'd like to know if UML is useful to describe heavily-templated code. I know that there is a notion of parametrized classes in UML (`vector<T>  <---- <<bind>> ---- vector<int>`), but this won't be enough to describe complex *duck-typed* relationships that we can have with templates. I can always put associations between such classes, but it seems to me that it won't actually help to understand how it works.

Moreover, considering for example the STL library, the algorithms are often implemented as functions, and thus don't fit very well into the OOP model, though they still behave quite like objects introducing associations between classes.

So, does it make sense to draw UML diagrams to describe such templated code? If so, which kinds of diagrams would be most useful - in "standard" OOP I've seen class diagrams being used most of the time, but probably for templated code some other kinds of diagrams would be more helpful? If UML is not well suitable for that, what else could I use?

Comment: +1 Since, I remembered the tortures to model templates with Telelogic Rhapsody.

Comment: "No," because the answer to the more general question "Is UML useful?" is "no."

Comment: @James McNellis: what *is* useful then? How would you make a high-level overview of a system? Digging into the source/comments to all those classes to understand how they are related doesn't look like a good option.

Comment: Good documentation and a couple of block diagrams depicting the system architecture.

Comment: @James: As far as I know, UML is just about standardization of block diagrams to avoid everyone inventing their own visual language. So what kind of block diagrams are you talking about exactly?

Comment: @James: I used to think that UML is useless a couple of years ago. But now I can't imagine how to develop complex systems without it!

Comment: @7vies: _"algorithms are often implemented as functions, and thus don't fit very well into the OOP model"_  Algorithms are not objects. And not everything is an object, so OOP is not an all-fitting tool.

Comment: @vies: "There are things that are objects. Things that have state and change their state are objects. And then there are things that are not objects. A binary search is not an object. It is an algorithm." [Alex Stepanov]

Comment: @SasQ: hence my question - are OOP tools such as UML somehow useful to describe templated code which is "not always" OOP, and to what extent. Otherwise, what could be used instead.

Comment: @7vies: UML is not only an OOP tool. It has also diagrams for program flow, state machines, module dependencies etc.

Comment: @7ives: As to the **templates**: I use to treat them as **"parametrized types"**, and their **template parameters** as a **part of their type name**. That is, in a similar way a C/C++ array is a container type parametrized by its size and the type of its elements. You can see that `int array[10]` and `std::vector<int>` are very similar semantically: you can treat the part in `<>` as a part of the name, ie. something equal to `vector_of_int` (you can even use a `typedef` for that).

Comment: @7ives: Templates are also a form of **duck typing**: they depend on particular properties of the template type ("The elements in this container must quack like a duck and have feathers."). So you can model them that way.

Comment: @SasQ: Yes I know all that :) Please re-read the question as you seem to repeat things I've *initially* said - parametrized classes, duck typing, other types of UML diagrams - all of that is mentioned in the text above. Parametrized classes is the easiest case, but with templates you can have complex duck-typed relations like bindings, type mappings, recursive type lists, and other not-so-OOP-like stuff. So my question is can we use UML to describe such relations, and which kind of UML diagrams could be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I think it depends.

If different instantiations will lead to significantly different behaviours or relationships, then while it would be possible to model with UML, it would be ugly. On the other hand, if the behaviour is really that different with different instantiations, I'm not sure templates are a good idea, anyway.

But if the relationships between classes remain more or less the same no matter how they're instantiated then an UML class diagram is going to be just as useful to model those relationships as it would be for non-parameterized classes.

Comment: This is true only until the templated classes behave as classes. Imagine an algorithm (templated function) that takes an iterator and a predicate, does something and writes results to an output container. How would I represent this kind of relations with a diagram? It is the function that creates an association between the iterator, predicate and container, but simply drawing this via associations wouldn't explain anything, moreover, there is far more than just one function...

Comment: @7vies: OOP (among other things) states "Everything is an object", so don't worry about functions:)... Remember Template Method, Strategy, Abstract Factory, Visitor...?

Comment: @Gabriel: Yes, that's why template metaprogramming is not so much OOP. The big difference that I can see is that OOP is about "complex objects, simple interaction", while templated code usually has way more complex interaction between classes. Some diagrams could still be useful, and that leads to my question.

Comment: @7vies: I don't think you understood my comment. OOP is about simple objects with simple interactions... AFAIK it is true templates (parametrized types) come from algebraic specifications, not from OOP. But metaprogramming is in the veins of Smalltalk. The patterns are all objects for behaviour - functors in C++.

Comment: @Gabriel: Now I don't understand you for sure :) Objects in OOP might have simple interfaces, but they can have a very complex underlying structure, so I wouldn't say they are always "simple". Anyway, the OOP approach clearly separates *objects* and *messages* between them. Functors/higher-order functions are related to functional programming which is clearly different from OOP. Metaprogramming applied to classes is a kind of mix of the two, so it is not obvious how this can be described using OOP-targeted instruments.

Comment: @7vies: it is not so important, but my point of view is, that objects have state, which might be structured, but shouldn't be too complicated, because objects expose behaviour dependent on their state, e.g. through methods. I don't think functions are messages, I think functions are in OOP the behaviour. Such behaviour can be encapsulated in a object - look at function objects (functors) and adjustable functions - Template Method design pattern.

Comment: @7vies Metaprogramming with classes is in Smalltalk and Ruby done through dynamic dispatch and delegation. You send and object a message, based on its state, it will decide to which class object the message should be delegated and that objects interprets the message. When your object changes its state, it can change also the class object delegate. This is similar to Chain of Responsibility design pattern. This is very OOP and has nothing to do with functional programming.